# Does JS recursion in for loop breaks after one recursion ends?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, recursion

I put a main div in it, but for loop broke after one child recursion ends, what should I do to check every children with recusion?
here is output:

```
direct: DIV main
direct: DIV basicFrame
direct: DIV basicFrame__name
direct: SPAN name
```

and loop broke after a first recursion ends.
as you can see, after first recursion (main -> basicFrame -> basicFrame__name -> name)
its loop broke (not passed to next children, infoFrame)
output supposed to print these too
direct: DIV infoFrame
direct: SPAN info
..and etc

this is js code

```
var typeDisplay = async function (target, findType) {
    if (findType == "id")
    {
        target = document.getElementById(target);
        target = [target];
    }
    else if (findType == "direct")
    {
        console.log("direct: " + target.tagName + " " + target.className); //output maker
        target = [target];
    }

    for (let ind = 0; ind < target.length; ind++)
    {
        const label = target[ind]; //get label from selection
        if (label != null)
        {
            for (let ind; ind < label.children.length; ind++); //get children of label
            {
                const subLabel = label.children[ind];
                if (typeof(subLabel) == "object")
                {
                    // doing some work
                    typeDisplay(subLabel, "direct"); //recursion to it's children
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
};
```

and this is input html form for js script

```
<div class="main" id="typeTarget"> <!--first parameter of function-->
               <div class="basicFrame">
                    <div class="basicFrame__name">
                        <span class="name">
                            wow
                        </span>
                        <button class="pen">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-image"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="faceFrame">
                        <img src="image.png" alt="no image" title="image">
                    </div>
               </div class="infoFrame">
                <span class="info">
                    Info :
                    <br>
                    <ul>
                        <li>this is list</li>
                        <li>list : 
                            <ul>
                                <li>a</li>
                                <li>b</li>
                                <li>c</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
           </div>

           <!--load java script-->
           <script>
               typeDisplay("typeTarget", "id");
           </script>
```

Comment: Why is `typeDisplay` an `async function` if it's not doing anything asynchronous?

Comment: It uses await in doing something line but I removed it here since it's too long.